# C++11 auto and size_type

Tags: c++, c++11, auto

Given the following usage of `auto`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i) {
   ...
}
```

It would be ideal for C++  to deduce `i` as `std::vector<int>::size_type`, but if it only looks at the initializer for `i`, it would see an integer. What is the deduced type of `i` in this case? Is this appropriate usage of `auto`?

Comment: Without know what you do with `i` it's impossible to tell.

Comment: I never knew that `auto` is used to deduce the appropriate type of a variable! does it?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER Yes, they changed its meaning in C++11.

Comment: @MarkB: Great!! so it's now similar to `var` in C#, is that right? also could you mention the section in the standard where the new meaning is defined?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER [dcl.spec.auto], and yes, it's almost if not entirely the same as C#'s `var` keyword.

Comment: For this particular case you're better off with a range-based for-loop, see my answer below.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Use `decltype` instead of `auto` to declare `i`.

```
for( decltype(v.size()) i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i ) {
  // ...
}
```

Even better, use iterators to iterate over the vector as @MarkB's answer shows.

Comment: Or even better, use range-based for loop, as in answer below.

Answer (score 13):

Why not solve your problem with iterators? Then the problem goes away:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto i = v.begin(); i != v.end(); ++i) {
   ...
}
```

If you want to iterate using indexes I would probably just explicitly spell out the type: You know what it is. `auto` is primarily used for unknown or hard-to-type template types I believe.

Comment: it should be begin( v ) and end( v)

Answer (score 7):

The answer to your question "Is this appropriate usage of auto?" is no for reasons explained in other answers. For the particular case of looping through the contents of a container, you are most likely better off with a range based for-loop:

const reference access to elements, `i` is `const int&`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (const auto& i :  v ) {
   std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

non-const reference access, `i` is `int&`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto& i :  v ) {
   ++i;
   std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

value access, `i` is `int`:

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (auto i :  v ) {
   ...
}
```

and so on. This also works for C-style arrays.

Answer (score 4):

`auto` gets the type exclusively from the initializer. No attention is paid to other uses, at least not for determining the variable's type. To take that into account as well, `decltype` is an option:

```
for (decltype(v.size()) i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
```

or, you may be able to rewrite the loop to go backwards:

```
for (auto i = v.size(); i-- != 0; )
```

or, you may be able to avoid the `for` loop entirely.