# Why does my for loop never end?

Tags: c++, c++11, for-loop

So, I have this code that is supposed to add each range that is going to be tested to the 'freqDistRanges' vector. 'values' is a vector of type double that holds the user input. My problem is that if I input less than ten values into the 'values' array the for loop never ends. I don't see why this would be, for example if there was only one value entered freqDistRange would equal 0.1. The for loop would stop when i > 0.1 and i would equal 0.1 on the second iteration and would be 0.2 on the second, which should end the for loop. What am I missing here, I feel like it is something simple that I overlooked. Thanks for any help.

```
double freqDistRange = ((double)values.size() / 10); // there will be ten ranges

// add each range to the 'ranges' vector
for (auto i = 0; i <= ((double)values.size() * freqDistRange); i +=     freqDistRange)
        freqDistRanges.push_back(i);
```

Comment: `i` is an `int`. If `i` is `0` and you add `0.1` to it, it's still `0`. If you add `0.1` to it a further 20,000 times, it's *still* `0`.

Comment: change to auto i = 0.0; instead of auto i = 0;

Comment: This is a pitfall with auto; [see here](http://adamromanek.blogspot.de/2014/11/the-auto-keyword-versus-portability.html) for further reading.

Comment: It has nothing to do with `auto`. The same issue would have arisen with `int`.

Comment: This has nothing to do with auto.  He's using the wrong type as the index of the for loop.  For that matter, a while loop is probably more appropriate here.  That link to the blog is click bait and just tells you how great auto is, which is unrelated to the issue at hand.

Comment: It has everything to do with `auto` if, as one might reasonably assume, explicitly writing `int` there would have made it immediately obvious that the type was wrong.

Comment: @PaulGriffiths it is immediately obvious here, too.  0 vs 0.0.

Comment: @thang: It obviously wasn't obvious to the OP. Obviously, it's obvious to anyone who can spot the obvious problem.

Comment: @Puppy it was clearly intended that `i` be `double`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`i` is an `int`, here, and can only hold integral values. If `i` is `0`, and you add `0.1` to it, it'll still be `0`. If you add `0.1` to it a million times, it'll *still* be `0`.

You should change:

```
auto i = 0;
```

to either:

```
double i = 0;
```

or:

```
auto i = 0.0;
```

There are no benefits to using `auto` in this particular case if you have to make sure to choose an initial value of the type you need. If you know you need type `double`, you may as well explicitly declare it as a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you intended a `double` as a loop counter, however `auto i = 0;` deduces type based on `0` which is an `int`. This is a pitfall to be aware of when using `auto` in a `for` loop. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9899011/c11-auto-and-size-type) for another SO question on the topic.

However, if you want to have exactly 11 steps then using `double` as the variable type is **not** a good idea. This is because floating-point arithmetic is inherently not perfectly precise, so due to rounding errors you could get either 10 or 12 steps instead.

To get precise behaviour use an integral type as the loop counter. Here:

```
double freqDistRange = values.size() / 10.0;

for (int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
{
    freqDistRanges.push_back( i * freqDistRange );
}
```